# GulpJs error handling without freezing

Tags: javascript, gulp, build-system

I'm trying to convert my sass to css along with a few other things. I'm having trouble handling the sass conversion if there is an error. I can make it tell me but then it hangs and I have to restart gulp. I miss type here and there and I ctrl+s religiously so It gets really annoying when every other typo I make crashes gulp. Here's what I have:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    var sassSrc = './src/scss/*.scss',
        sassDst = './build/css',
        htmlSrc = './src/*.html',
        htmlDst = './build';

gulp.src(sassSrc, {unpipeOnError: false})
    .pipe(watch(function(files) {
        return files.pipe(plumber())
            .pipe(sass())
            .on("error", notify.onError())
            .pipe(prefix("last 3 version", "> 1%", 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', "Android 4"))
            .pipe(minifyCSS())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(sassDst))
            .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
    }));

    gulp.src(htmlSrc)
    .pipe(watch(function(files) {
        return files.pipe(minifyHTML())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(htmlDst));
    }));
});
```

Comment: I can add .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true})) to make it stop haulting the gulp file but I can't get it to also set a Notify. It will print to console but I don't want to have to peak over every time.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter) class from Node. Instead of passing `notify.onError()` directly, also emit the `end` event. Change the relevant code to the following block:

```
.on('error', function() {
    notify.onError().apply(this, arguments);
    this.emit('end');
})
```

and `gulp-watch` should continue to respond to changes, even when an error is raised. Hope this helps!